# Keras Metric strange behavior

Tags: keras, metrics

I am trying to define a Keras metric that returns a rounded value. (Normally K.round() can't be used in the Loss since it's not differentiable but I think it can be used on the Metric).

However despite using K.round() the metric consistently has decimal places, giving me values like 2.0812 and similar. It is worth mentioning that my y_true are 3 value float lists like [1., 3., 5.], [2., 5., 1.] and so on.

To try and understand what is happening I defined a very simple metric.

```
def simplemetric(y_true, y_pred):
    return (y_true)
```

I was expecting this to give me an error, but it returns values around 2.089 that vary slightly on each epoch but not with batch size (which is 128).

I then tried a different metric.

```
def simplemetric(y_true, y_pred):
    return (K.round(K.sum(y_true)))
```

This gives me values around 800.142 that vary slightly on each epoch but not with batch number.

As a final test I tried:

```
def simplemetric(y_true, y_pred):
    return (y_true*0 + 10.0)
```

Which gives me the expected value of 10.0 on every epoch.

So what is happening on the previous cases? Why can't I get a whole number, and what is the meaning of the ~2. and ~800 keras is somehow calculating out of lists like [1., 2., 5.]?

Comment: Is it training metric or validation metric that varies?

Comment: Keras computes the average over samples behind the scene.  With multiple column case, keras further compute the average across columns.  The first example therefore computes the average of matrix, which is around 2.  The second  case computes the sum of matrix, which is around `128 batch * avg 2 * 3 cols = 768`.  It is not far from 800.  Further insight requires reproducible code to play with.